# Why cant i increase the height of this div (using bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, height

Im trying to increase the height of the sidebar, i want it to be the same height as the page.[picture of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F6hr.png)
I want the box on the left to touch te bottom but when i use the class h-100 it does not work.

The html code of the element:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2 pt-5 sidebar h-100 sticky-top w100">
             ...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sidebar actually have the same height of your page. Is your page that is not touching the bottom of the screen.

You have two ways to fix this.

**1. set body height to 100vh in your styles.css**

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**2. wrap your page in a div**

```
<div style="height: 100vh">
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2 pt-5 sidebar h-100 sticky-top w100">
             ...
</div>
```

Comment: Ty for your help the first option did unfortunately not work, the second one did but i only had to add the h-100 class to the div with container-fluid. But now i have a problem that my sidebalk does not move with the screen, i kinda want it to move like this example i found on the bootstrap site: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/dashboard/#. do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Thats because the position of the exaple you posted is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> h-100 will work only if the parent div has 100% height !
>   you can use 100vh instead of above if you cant set the height to the parent

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your css file

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    myNewDivHeight{
        height:250px;
    }
}
```

add this class to your div

```
class="col-md-12 myNewDivHeight"
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to set height of a div first of all you have to make the div as `display-inline-block`. Because inline element doesn't allows height and div is a inline element. Set height manually using css

```
.container-fluid {
    height: 100px;
}
```

2. If h-100 means `height: 100%` according to the content of the div or child elements. So the height will be only the text height.

   ```
   <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-2 pt-5 sidebar h-100 w-100 d-inline-block sticky-top">
   ```

   test text